# OpenVPN connects and access to ip works but not url in browser

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, openvpn, kvm-virtualization

I have been struggling for 2 days to setup Openvpn access to one of my servers but something doesn't work.

First about my setup:

My server is Debian 6 installed on vps on kvm environment. I have debian 6 net install which comes with no services at all, so i installed iptables, openvpn, bind dns, and dns masq.

My pc is Xubuntu 14.04 desktop install.

Well up to the problem. The problem is that i can't browse any sites when i am connected to vpn. BUT i can for example connect to email in thunderbird. i can browse my other server via ipaddress and i can ping any site. But when i type url in browser it won't load at all. So it seems that anything IP related works, but resolving an url doesn't work.

Here is my openvpn server config.

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh1024.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
max-clients 2
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log         openvpn.log
verb 5
```

I also set

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward to 1
```

And in dnsmasq i set to listen both interfaces.

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1,10.8.0.1
```

and mind them together

```
bind-interfaces
```

And i also set a routing table in iptables to this

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

So i do get able to connect and ping google.com works, access to ip address works. but in browsers when i try to go to google.com it finds it but could not load a page.

And to mention server is an old one in use i had it for a year working fine before, but it failed due to failed hdd and i had to reinstall it and start over again, so the OS is new on it.

EDIT: i just checked a logs and i get this error

```
MULTI: bad source address from client [214.236.214.100], packet dropped
```

and 214.236.214.100 is my ip address that my computer use and im getting it from my home router.

EDIT#2: I just got an email about suspicious sign in from google from an ip from the server. I am running thunderbird on my ps and this means that once i am on vpn connected my thunderbird connects to the emails but i still can't resolve url address browsing.

EDIT#3: Here is the latest client config i tried to use to connect on my vpn.

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote myserverip 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert myclient.crt
key myclient.key
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Comment: if you traceroute are you going through the VPN?

Comment: Yes when i am connected on vpn and trace it goes through vnp, i just checked logs and i get packet dropped error, check the edit i made on my post.

Comment: What's your client config? Is your client Linux or Windows?

Comment: It doesn't matter i have windows 7 on laptop, windows 8 on one desktop, and xubuntu on my other desktop and also tried on xubuntu on virtualbox, it's always the same. ill post client conf now.

Comment: You have a split-tunneling problem. Please print out your routes on the OpenVPN server and your client.  Also, you need to decide if you want all your traffic to go through the VPN or if you just want specific traffic to go through the VPN.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is DNS related. You're pushing two DNS servers to your VPN client. You usually don't need to push DNS servers unless you have a DNS server in your VPN environment that handles local DNS entries not shared to the rest of the world. (Corporate networks typically have these internal DNS servers).

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

In this above example, your computer will look to 10.8.0.1 for DNS resolution. You can just comment these two lines out and your OpenVPN setup should work.

Comment: if i do disable dhcp-option i don't even get a page loading at all, as soon as i type google.com browser throws me an error server not found. When dhcp push is enabled. i get loading a google.com but it just get stuck and not loading the content.

Comment: You still need to specify a real DNS server. Is 10.8.0.1 a DNS server? I'm guessing not. The second one is Google DNS. Move 8.8.8.8 to the top entry and 8.8.4.4 as the second entry (Both of those are Google public DNS). Or alternatively, use your ISPs DNS servers or setup your own.

Comment: Even when i use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as dns it doesn't work i tried with my isp dns it didn't worked too, and this was my last choice, i used bind and dnsmasq to make my own dns and dmsmasq to connect vpn with my dns and still doesn't work. I think this is not related to dns it's rather some kind of issue to packet forwarding or iptables. but when i turn of iptables it's the same. or i am wrong.